# InstalledAppFlow automatically get authorization code

Tags: python, google-authentication, google-api-python-client

I am using **InstalledAppFlow** imported from `google_auth_oauthlib.flow`. Every time I run the code, I have to get the authorization code manually. The code will show like this:

`Please visit this URL to authorize this application: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=929791903032-hpdm8djidqd8o5nqg2gk636efau34ea6q.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=https%3A%22F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyt-analytics-monetary.readonly&state=a0drph4tJFDc2rIGtdwUStIGbRKNnkv18&prompt=consent&access_type=offline`

`Enter the authorization code:` 
Then I have to click to the accounts.google.com above to enter the authorization code then paste it:
**`4/0gCyNaDZeNRr5pnvkXFO1HvLjsq5IbjVYjETaUtlq8_1PqoaY9totzs`**

**My question is how to do this step automatically not manually?**

Comment: Did you do any research? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I'm certain others have asked how one can store credentials and then use them instead of reprompting...

Comment: If you use the `Flow#run_local_server()` method, instead of `run_console`, it will handle the auth code transmission from web page to script. As described in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Like tehhowch said their documentation which automates this process uses:

```
flow.run_local_server()
```

Rather than:

```
flow.run_console()
```

And then to automate it for next time you run it:

```
flow.run_local_server()
with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
    pickle.dump(credentials, token)
```

It should work without prompts after the first run.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/python

Comment: After I authorize the access I get redirected to localhost which just gives me a crashed website with: This site can’t be reached

Comment: @Lalle I'm hitting the exact same issue, which I suspect comes from trying this in a remote server. Did you find a workaround?

Comment: @Lalle I'm sure there is a better solution, but for now I managed to create the needed token.json by simply authorizing access from my local laptop, instead of from the jupyter notebook running in the cluster.